# Python re.compile: unsupported operand type(s) for &: str and int

Tags: python, regex

I have following code:

```
import re
r = re.compile('^[0-9 ]{1,4}Ty', 'i')
```

I get unexpected error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/re.py", line 219, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/re.py", line 275, in _compile
    bypass_cache = flags & DEBUG
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'
```

How to fix it?

Comment: @vaultah thank you, `re.IGNORECASE` instead of `'i'` works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`'i'` is not a valid flag value, because [all compilation flags used by `re` functions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#compilation-flags) must be integers (`re` uses bitwise operations to manipulate flags).

Use `re.I` (or `re.IGNORECASE`) instead

```
import re
r = re.compile('^[0-9 ]{1,4}Ty', re.I)
```

Technically you *can* specify flags as strings but in this case they'll have to be included in the pattern:

```
import re
r = re.compile('(?i)^[0-9 ]{1,4}Ty')
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

> *(?aiLmsux)*
>
> One or more letters from the set `'a'`, `'i'`, `'L'`, `'m'`, `'s'`,
>   `'u'`, `'x'`. The group matches the empty string; the letters set the
>   corresponding flags.

So `(?i)` has the same effect as passing `re.I` (or `re.IGNORECASE`) to `compile`.

Answer (score 0):

Flags are predefined constants in `re` module:

```
re.compile('..', re.IGNORECASE).
```